# Is -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 safe for production in a containered environment?

Tags: java, docker, jvm

Java 8/9 brought support for `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` (with `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`). This sets `-XX:MaxRAM` to the cgroup memory limit. Per default, the JVM allocates roughly 25% of the max RAM, because `-XX:MaxRAMFraction` defaults to 4.

Example:

```
MaxRAM = 1g
MaxRAMFraction = 4
JVM is allowed to allocate: MaxRAM / MaxRAMFraction = 1g / 4 = 256m
```

Using only 25% of the quota seems like waste for a deployment which (usually) consists of a single JVM process. So now people set `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1`, so the JVM is theoretically allowed to use 100% of the MaxRAM.

For the 1g example, this often results in heap sizes around 900m. This seems a bit high - there is not a lot of free room for the JVM or other stuff like remote shells or out-of-process tasks.

So is this configuration (`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1`) considered safe for prod or even best practice? Or should I still hand pick `-Xmx`, `-Xms`, `-Xss` and so on?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211535/how-do-i-elegantly-and-safely-maximize-the-amount-of-heap-space-allocated-to-a-j

Comment: Did you read [Running a JVM in a container without getting killed](https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/05/31/running-a-jvm-in-a-container-without-getting-killed/)?

Comment: I did. Someone asked in the comments whether allocating more than 90% of the available RAM for heap was safe and the author replied "Supposedly the MaxRAMFraction=1 will still leave some room for the other non-heap memory. I haven’t done extensive testing though". Does not seem like a definitive answer.

Comment: I know you are asking for Java8/9, but just an fyi Java 10 has added new option -XX:MaxRAMPercentage which is more sensible and gives more flexibility to specify the max heap size. So you can say -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80 to tell JVM to use 80% of container memory as the heap. And the default max heap size is also closer to the container memory limit.

Comment: why is -Xss used for

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We did some simple testing which showed that setting `-XX:MaxRAM=$QUOTA` and `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1` results in killed containers under load. The JVM allocates more than 900M heap, which is way too much. `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=2` seems safe(ish).

Keep in mind that you may want to leave headroom for other processes like getting a debug shell (`docker exec`) or diagnostics in the container.

---

Edit: we've written up what we've learned in detail in an [article](https://www.atamanroman.dev/development/2018/11/10/jvm-memory-settings-container-environment.html). Money quotes:

> **TL'DR:**
> Java memory management and configuration is still complex. Although the JVM can read cgroup memory limits and adapt memory usage accordingly since Java 9/8u131, it’s not a golden bullet. You need to know what `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` does and you need to fine tune some parameters for every deployment. Otherwise you risk wasting resources and money or getting your containers killed at the worst time possible. `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1` is especially dangerous. Java 10+ brings a lot of improvements but still needs manual configuration. To be safe, load test your stuff.

and

> The most elegant solution is to upgrade to Java 10+. Java 10 deprecates `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` (11) and introduces `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` (12), which supersedes it. It also introduces `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` (13) which takes a value between 0 and 100. This allows fine grained control of the amount of RAM the JVM is allowed to allocate. Since `+UseContainerSupport` is enabled by default, everything should work out of the box.

---

Edit #2: we've [written a little bit more](https://www.atamanroman.dev/development/2019/09/11/usecontainersupport-to-the-rescue.html) about `-XX:+UseContainerSupport`

> Java 10 introduced `+UseContainerSupport` (enabled by default) which makes the JVM use sane defaults in a container environment. This feature is backported to Java 8 since 8u191, potentially allowing a huge percentage of Java deployments in the wild to properly configure their memory.

Comment: We have done similar testing.  We found that the non-heap memory allocation tends to be fairly fixed. We tested with Spring Boot 2, we had to set the fraction to 4, if we had the memory around 500MB, but as we went out to 1G, we could drop down.   And for even larger containers, 90% left enough for the app to perform fine.  (4gb memory in the container.)

Comment: 4GB per container? Did you find that was the best way to optimise performance? I have been trying to increase load but it is difficult to find the right number of containers and memory per container.

Comment: What numbers in parentheses does mean?

Comment: Sadly, The `xxxRAMPercentage` are still only affecting the heap, not the whole memory consumption of the JVM process (as soon from the OS/hypervisor)

Answer (score 22):

The recent oracle-jdk-8(8u191) brings the following options to allow Docker container users to gain more fine grained control over the amount of system memory that will be used for the Java Heap:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage
-XX:MinRAMPercentage
```

> Three new JVM options have been added to allow Docker container users
>   to gain more fine grained control over the amount of system memory
>   that will be used for the Java Heap:
>
> -XX:InitialRAMPercentage
>   -XX:MaxRAMPercentage
>   -XX:MinRAMPercentage These options replace the deprecated Fraction forms (-XX:InitialRAMFraction, -XX:MaxRAMFraction, and
>   -XX:MinRAMFraction).

See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u191-relnotes-5032181.html

Comment: These flags are available in JDK 10+ https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8186248 However, `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` is available now with `8u191`.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder I write a simple demo to test it, and it works on jdk-8u191, see https://github.com/alex-lx/jdk-8-heap-test

Comment: I tried with `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75` and it gave me an error, maybe the fraction is required?!? Also interesting is that the bug itself does not mention a fix as part of `8u191`.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder, It might be unreasonable, but in my test, the percentage must be a float number like 75.0, and another point should be mentioned that `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` and `-XX:MinRAMPercentage` should be used together.

Comment: Since the 8u191's release note include this feature, I think maybe someone forgot to update the bug :-P. Yes, it's really confused.

Comment: Seems kinda broken in `8u191` one can use it as expected in (at least) 11. The requirement to use both max and min always together also makes little sense.

Comment: @a.l. `MaxRAMPercentage` and `MinRAMPercentage` are different things and do not influence each other. One counts towards devices with small physical memory and the other not.

Comment: @Eugene I agree these options should be independency. However, I did a test which indicates they're not, it's too long to remember the details of the test, and I can't reproduce the expected right now :-(, so I guess I made a mistake in that test.