# Setting memory limits for kubernetes containers in conjunction with java heap

Tags: java, kubernetes, heap-memory

I would like to know,  if there is an optimal approach for setting memory limits for Kubernetes containers, especially for applications running java.

For Java applications, we have to set a heap value in conjunction with Kubernetes resources. it's like we're kinda forced to guess at a memory limit for the Kubernetes microservice.

To be more clear,

- in java the heap memory can be limited to memory limits defined in the container, but how to arrive at a specific limit value ??
- If we don't set up limits for the container, then the java heap considers the underlying node memory limits rather than at container limits, so it can extend the pod limit to max memory,  which can stress the other pods running in that node.
- If we don't set up enough memory limits at the container, then we can see containers getting killed with OOM errors.

The possible solutions, I can think of is

1. Monitoring the microservice for some period of time and based on the utilization, choosing the limits
2. Implementing some load testing mechanism and based on the observation setting the limits

Other than the above, I would like to get some comments if there is any other approach followed by anyone in setting memory limits for Kubernetes containers.
Has anyone encountered this earlier!!

Comment: This seems similar to [How do I elegantly and safely maximize the amount of heap space allocated to a Java application in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211535/how-do-i-elegantly-and-safely-maximize-the-amount-of-heap-space-allocated-to-a-j)  If you have access to the [vertical pod autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) it can address this somewhat.  But fundamentally, it's what you say: set Kubernetes-level resource limits, let the JVM pick them up automatically, and incrementally tune them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have encountered the issue multiple times. You definitely want to keep the memory limit for the k8 to avoid the noisy neighbour problems. The possible solutions you have mentioned are right. Monitoring and load testing are a must to arrive at the number.

Along with these, I used the profiling of Java processes to see how GC is getting triggered and whether the memory usage should remain the same or increase with the increase of load. Profiling is a very powerful tool to provide some insights into suboptimal usage of data structures as well.

**What to profile**

While doing the Java profiling, you need to check

- What's the Eden and old-gen usage
- How often full GC is running, the memory utilisation will increase and decrease after the full GC. See the [GC pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/interesting-garbage-collection-patterns)
- How many objects are getting created
- CPU usage, (will increase during the full GC)

**How to profile Java application**

Here are a few good resources

- [https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers#:~:text=A%20Java%20Profiler%20is%20a,thread%20executions%2C%20and%20garbage%20collections](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers#:%7E:text=A%20Java%20Profiler%20is%20a,thread%20executions%2C%20and%20garbage%20collections).
- https://medium.com/platform-engineer/guide-to-java-profilers-e344ce0339e0

**How to Profile Kubernetes Application with Java**

- https://medium.com/swlh/introducing-kubectl-flame-effortless-profiling-on-kubernetes-4b80fc181852
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHTWdkCUAoI

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am not so familiar with profiling of java process, can you elaborate your answer with some example on how to add that configuration to kubernetes deployments and how that effects or analyzes the performance?

Comment: Updated Please take a look. You can use the profiling to come up with the memory utilization number for K8. There is no K8 deployment associated with the profiling. Generally, we do the profiling first to see if the Java application has any memory issue, then use the java application in k8.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the memory limits for applications in the cloud is kind of a balancing act because on the one hand, you want to reduce memory consumption, but on the other hand, meeting user demands may require allocating more memory.

Therefore, the first thing is to determine what your application should do and at what price. Load testing is great, but you should also utilize stress testing, i.e., how many resources your application requires at peak load. Otherwise, your services may crash.
Concerning the performance testing, I ran into an interesting presentation from Devoxx with a detailed discussion of necessary tests for optimal Kubernetes scaling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQJ6B35-eWs